# Calling a function within a Linq query

Tags: linq

If I want to iterate through a collection, and call a function on each element in the collection, I could go with :

```
foreach (var obj in objColl)
{
    MyFunction(obj);
}
```

Should I want to do this with linq, I can use either of those :

```
//#1
var unused = (from var obj in objColl select MyFunction(obj)).ToList();

//#2
var unused = objColl.Select(obj => MyFunction(obj)).ToList();
```

I know this works, but it doesn't seem right. Of course, my actual cases are more complex queries that that, but it comes down to this since I could build my IQueryable with Linq and iterate through it and call the function.

Edit:
Here is one example of what I did. (Item# are things I can't disclose)

```
var dummyValue = (from
                  Item7 in dal.GetAgencyConvertions().Where(age => age.SourceName == "Item1" && age.TargetName == "Item2")
                  join Item6 in dal.GetAgencyConvertions().Where(age => age.SourceName == "Item2" && age.TargetName == "Item3") on Item6.TargetValue equals Item7.SourceValue
                  join agency in dal.GetAgencies() on Item7.SourceValue equals agency.Agency
                  orderby Item7.TargetValue
                  select vl.ValueListItems.Add(agency.ID, Item7.TargetValue)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with the simple `foreach`, as you are clearly wanting to perform an action on (and/or using) the objects in your collection as opposed to wishing to project/filter/group/etc. the items in the sequence. LINQ is about the latter set of operations.

**Edit:** In the case of your update, I would simply create a query, and then iterate over the query in the foreach to perform the action.

```
var query = from Item7 in dal.GetAgencyConvertions().Where(age => age.SourceName == "Item1" && age.TargetName == "Item2") 
            join Item6 in dal.GetAgencyConvertions().Where(age => age.SourceName == "Item2" && age.TargetName == "Item3") on Item6.TargetValue equals Item7.SourceValue  
            join agency in dal.GetAgencies() on Item7.SourceValue equals agency.Agency 
            orderby Item7.TargetValue 
            select new { ID = agency.ID, Value = Item7.TargetValue };

foreach (var item in query)
    vl.ValueListItems.Add(item.ID, item.Value);
```

To be frank, you have the same loop happening in your code, you merely mask it by using the `ToList()` extension method. As a byproduct, you are creating a list of values that you have no intention of using, while somewhat obfuscating the true intention of the code, all to save maybe a few characters.

Comment: I'll go with this, even though the result in CIL would most likely be the same, just to keep the code clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a query *shouldn't* have any side effects (i.e. it shouldn't modify the state of the data or other data in your application) which raises the question, **does `MyFunction` modify the state of your application?** If it does, then you should use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Well, one case I have is to create a value list. If your not familiar with it, it's an Infragistics kind of custom dictionary. I'll update my question to have this example as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about an Each() extension method?

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, Action<T> action)
{
    if (target == null) return;
    foreach (T obj in target)
        action(obj);
}
```

Comment: Not a terrible answer, but there are, I think, some [solid opinions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/08/why-i-don-t-use-the-foreach-extension-method.aspx) on why not to do this. :)